# Embedding a back and forward arrows, home button, and download manager in a quickly application

Tags: python, gedit, quickly, glade

I have downloaded a set of icons to use for my web browser that I'm creating and would like to use. I know how to add the icons, but I only know the code for the refresh button. My question is what is the code for the back and forward arrows? It would also be so helpful if I would know the code for the home button and how to make the web browser manage downloads.

I'm using WebkitGtk as the web browser view.

The images are found [here](http://www.openclipart.org)

Comment: The images have nothing to do with how the code works. Specify what you use as the browser view: WebkitGtk, gtkmozembed, ... Have you read the reference manual for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your edit says you're using WebkitGtk, which has simple API calls for this.

Have a look at the [reference manual](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/webkitgtk-webkitwebview.html), especially the `webview.go_back()` and `webview.go_forward()` methods.

A home button is pretty easy as well. You probably have stored the home url in a config file or constant/variable in your code, just load a new page with that value when the home button is pressed.